# Apollo Server Health Check custom response

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I am currently looking to provide more information to the health check other than status: pass. Is this possible? I tried sending test strings unfortunately, I am still seeing the same response json. Thank you in advance!

Code:

```
       onHealthCheck: (req) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                if(true) {
                    console.log(req);
                    resolve(req);
                    //resolve("test")
                } else {
                    reject();
                }
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onHealthCheck implementation looks like this (express is used):

```
    if (onHealthCheck) {
      onHealthCheck(req)
        .then(() => {
          res.json({ status: 'pass' });
        })
        .catch(() => {
          res.status(503).json({ status: 'fail' });
        });
    }
```

so as you can see, it returns hardcoded value.

You can always implement your custom health check also using express.

Comment: thank you for your response! I was looking into this approach as well. do you know if I can create my custom url? every time I try using:  await this.server.getMiddleware().use('/customHealth', (req, res, next) => {...});  it still takes me to the graph ql playground. Any idea why that is?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're using, but you can integrate Apollo Server into Express and then create custom endpoint using Express: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v1/servers/express/